# how to reset GET variables

Tags: php

Please pardon my PHP noobness! I want a single page to display a particular navigation based on the incoming link. It's set up as follows:

page1.php list item:

```
<li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'wood-species.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>href="wood-species.php?name=standard">Wood Species</a></li>
```

page2.php list item:

```
<li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'wood-species.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>href="wood-species.php?name=premium">Wood Species</a></li>
```

So the first link will set the name variable to "standard" using the GET method, and the second link will set it to "premium".  So what I want to happen is that 'wood-species.php' displays with the appropriate navigation, but I'm not sure how to destroy or unset the 'name' variable.

Here's what I tried to use, obviously not getting it done...

```
 <?php

    $woodclass = $_GET['name'];
    if($woodclass="premium") {
    require("includes/premium-wide-navigation.php"); 
    echo"premium";
    clearit();
    }

    else if($woodclass="standard") {
    require("includes/standard-wide-navigation.php");
    echo"standard";
    clearit();
    }
    else {
    //
    }

    function clearit () {
    unset($GLOBALS['woodclass']);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that unset($_GET['name']); should do the job.

Comment: none of these suggestions are working for some reason. The first require statement pops up every time, even after I clear the cache..there must be another issue I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unset a variable using `unset($myVar);`.

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript

Form:

`<form method="get" action="<? print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="number" size="5" maxlength="5">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
        <input id="refresh_custom_input" type="reset">
    </form>`

Javascript:

```
//refresh GET variable
$('#refresh_custom_input').click(function() {

    var query = window.location.search.substring(1)

    if(query.length) {
       if(window.history != undefined && window.history.pushState != undefined) {
            window.history.pushState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);
       }
    } 

    window.location.reload(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`header("location: somewhere.php");` will get rid of any $_GET variables.

Answer (score 0):

if you're dealing with conditionals and you simply want to clear any get requests from the url, you can do this

```
 if (!empty($_GET))
    header("Location: page.php");
```

this really only works for conditionals tho